# How to run a clone of reddit.com website. Reddit.com source code gives error while implementing on Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic)

Tags: python, pylons, paster, reddit

I am implementing the reddit.com source code on ubuntu karmic 9.10.

I have followed all the steps and in one step where i am using paster command it throws an error. 
$paster shell example.ini

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-
py2.6.egg/pylons/middleware.py", line 11, in 
    from webhelpers.rails.asset_tag import javascript_path
**ImportError: No module named rails.asset_tag**

I have checked for the version for webhelpers, its the latest installed.

Could anybody tell me that by installing another version of webhelpers will solve this problem?

Or Shall i modify the code?

Its a reddit.com source code written in python, using pylons framework.

I am unable to decide that whether by installing any previous version of webhelpers helps or shall i modify the code.

If there is anybody who have implemented the reddit.com website please help me or suggest me the best way.

thanks
SIA

Comment: Can you successfully `import webhelpers.rails.asset_tag import javascript_path` from a normal Python shell?

Comment: Thanks for coming forward to answer me.

No, i get a long list of error and in the traceback this was the last error

I am new to python, but a asp.net/php developer since a decade. 
Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that all the libraries needed by your Reddit clone are on [Python's module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).  There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this.  The easiest is probably to just use [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)' `easy_install` command to install them (though this is my own personal least favorite way to install Python libraries, and also opens new cans of worms in the form of "Why not use [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) or [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instead?").

The next easiest way is probably to download and unpack the source code for the libraries you need and either a) `setup.py install` them or b) add their directories to your `$PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` variables.

The documentation linked above has more info on how to control the module search path.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I tried it, its giving an error while compiling libxml2, and now it looks i lost the previous installation of libxml2

Comment: In this case, it's WebHelpers that needs to be downgraded. Check this post for more information: http://groups.google.com/group/reddit-dev/msg/344fd022ce271d7a